# can't boot debian, can't change anything with efibootmgr

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, debian, efi

After a kernel update (Debian Stable/Jessie), my system wouldn't boot. I got back into it by installing ubuntu, and the ubuntu loader will let me boot debian.

So now I'm trying to get debian to repair the boot process, but it seems as though efibootmgr is impotent:

Here's the current status:

```
# efibootmgr -v

BootCurrent: 0000
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
Boot0000* Ubuntu    HD(1,800,fa000,c865d688-f250-471e-9d54-bad998d64e31)File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* UEFI Onboard LAN IPv6 ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,0)PCI(0,0)MAC(MAC(74867a15fbd5,0)030d3c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000RC
Boot0002* UEFI Onboard LAN IPv4 ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,0)PCI(0,0)MAC(MAC(74867a15fbd5,0)RC
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,800,fa000,c865d688-f250-471e-9d54-bad998d64e31)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...d...............
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
```

And I thought this would fix it:

```
# grub-install /dev/sda

Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
efibootmgr: Could not set variable Boot0003: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not prepare boot variable: No such file or directory
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

But actually it looks like efibootmgr can't change anything at all

```
# efibootmgr -t 10
efibootmgr: Could not set Timeout: No such file or directory
```

Something is borked, and it looks like this might have been the problem in the first place, anyone got any idea what?

As I say, ubuntu managed to install fine on the same system, so I'm reluctant to believe that it's the computer rather than Debian that's broken.

---

Here's an strace of the failing timeout command:

There are some errors towards the end (No space left on device??)

```
root@dell-3521:/home/john# strace efibootmgr -t 10
execve("/bin/efibootmgr", ["efibootmgr", "-t", "10"], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xcff000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc3cfd1c000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=126215, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 126215, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc3cfcfd000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpci.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0%\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=52448, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2147632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc3cf8f1000
mprotect(0x7fc3cf8fc000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc3cfafc000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xb000) = 0x7fc3cfafc000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=109144, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2204200, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc3cf6d6000
mprotect(0x7fc3cf6f0000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc3cf8ef000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7fc3cf8ef000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libefivar.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=63520, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc3cfcfc000
mmap(NULL, 2159576, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc3cf4c6000
mprotect(0x7fc3cf4cd000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc3cf6cc000, 40960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fc3cf6cc000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1738176, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3844640, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc3cf11b000
mprotect(0x7fc3cf2bd000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc3cf4bc000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a1000) = 0x7fc3cf4bc000
mmap(0x7fc3cf4c2000, 14880, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc3cf4c2000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220:\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=84856, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2189928, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc3cef04000
mprotect(0x7fc3cef18000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc3cf117000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13000) = 0x7fc3cf117000
mmap(0x7fc3cf119000, 6760, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc3cf119000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc3cfcfb000
mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc3ced00000
mprotect(0x7fc3ced03000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc3cef02000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fc3cef02000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc3cfcfa000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc3cfcf9000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc3cfcf8000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fc3cfcf9700) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc3cf4bc000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc3cef02000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc3cf117000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc3cf6cc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc3cf8ef000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc3cfafc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60e000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fc3cfd1e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fc3cfcfd000, 126215)          = 0
access("/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/", F_OK) = 0
statfs("/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/", {f_type="SYSFS_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="dell-3521", ...}) = 0
access("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/new_var", F_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/firmware/efi/vars/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
brk(0)                                  = 0xcff000
brk(0xd28000)                           = 0xd28000
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 159 entries */, 32768)   = 12872
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Boot0000-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "B\0o\0o\0t\0000\0000\0000\0000\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2084
read(3, "", 2012)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Boot0001-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "B\0o\0o\0t\0000\0000\0000\0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2084
read(3, "", 2012)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Boot0002-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "B\0o\0o\0t\0000\0000\0000\0002\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2084
read(3, "", 2012)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Boot0004-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "B\0o\0o\0t\0000\0000\0000\0004\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2084
read(3, "", 2012)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Boot2001-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "B\0o\0o\0t\0002\0000\0000\0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2084
read(3, "", 2012)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Timeout-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/data", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/new_var", O_WRONLY) = 3
write(3, "T\0i\0m\0e\0o\0u\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 2084) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
umask(0)                                = 022
umask(022)                              = 0
chmod("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Timeout-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e0980/", 021371157541) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
chmod("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Timeout-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e0980/attributes", 021371157541) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
chmod("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Timeout-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e0980/data", 021371157541) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
chmod("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Timeout-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e0980/guid", 021371157541) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
chmod("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Timeout-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e0980/raw_var", 021371157541) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
chmod("/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Timeout-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e0980/size", 021371157541) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "efibootmgr: ", 12efibootmgr: )            = 12
write(2, "Could not set Timeout", 21Could not set Timeout)   = 21
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "No such file or directory\n", 26No such file or directory
) = 26
exit_group(14)                          = ?
+++ exited with 14 +++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be some combination of Windows screwing up the system and Dell's hardware being rubbish:

http://www.c0le.org/2014/12/dual-booting-debian-jessie-and-windows.html

Every time you boot Windows (I never do! It happened by accident!), it tries to add its own bootloader and that buggers everything up.

What appears to fix it is to do this at a Windows command prompt!:

(<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then Command Prompt (Admin))

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi
```

Apparently this makes Windows use debian's grub bootloader.

Then when Windows tries to screw things up, it screws them up so that they work!

Bloody pile.

Comment: While your answer is funny, the other answer may be more helpful in general.

Answer (score 3):

I've both heard reports of and seen cases where the NVRAM contents (where the `efibootmgr` boot order and boot entries are stored) becomes damaged, making further changes to it difficult or impossible. The only fix I know of is to use the firmware's options to reset all settings to the default. This should clear *all* the entries out of the NVRAM, which will render your computer unbootable unless you have something in the fallback filename position (`EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`) or you use a removable medium (like an Ubuntu installation disk). You can use an emergency disk or fallback boot loader to boot an OS and add back whatever entries you want.

That said, I can't be 100% positive that you're experiencing this problem. The symptoms align, but it could be you're running into another issue, in which case attempting the recovery I've just suggested will be a waste of time that might actually make matters worse. You'll have to decide for yourself whether it's worth the risk.

Comment: An emergency boot disk might not be necessary. After clearing the boot entries, you can boot into the EFI shell and create the boot entries you need using the `bcfg` command (type `help bcfg`).

Comment: Or if `bcfg` is not available, you can always execute your boot manager or EFISTUB kernel directly (including command line arguments) as long as the file name ends in .EFI (and if it doesn't you can rename it).